# Cube/Mongo: Custom metric resolutions (step)

Tags: mongodb, d3.js, cube, cubism.js

According the documentation square/cube supports 5 metric resolutions (step), the lowest is 10 seconds. I understand this is required in order to allow pyramidal reducers. Will cube work correctly (though less efficiently) with any arbitrary step value or are there other problems? If it is just an efficiency issue, how bad would it be - even with built in step values it takes time for the cache to fill for all options.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar situation when creating horizon charts of stock data. Some stocks are not traded at all moments during the day.

In this situation, I "backfilled" in the intermediate values and created a uniform distribution. Essentially, I took the latest data and added it to a newer time stamp until new data was available.

For example, if I had the following prices for minute-by-minute data:

```
11:15 AM -> 112.0
11:18 AM -> 115.0
```

my program created the following "imaginary" intervals.

```
11:15 AM -> 112.0
11:16 AM -> 112.0
11:17 AM -> 112.0
11:18 AM -> 115.0
```

My program used a JSON data source, so manipulating these values was really easy. I have never used cube/mongo and so I don't know how easy it will be to do the same there.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: thanks but not sure if this is the issue, I have all the data but cube does not allow to query for certain intervals